# Google images - is possible to get image list passing image to URL?

Tags: android, image, google-image-search

I would like to search similar images on Google images from my mobile app by passing URL param of the image (without using Google image search API).

**Something like this:**
http://images.google.com/imghp?hl=cs&url=http://web.com/image.jpg

How can i do it?

Thanks for any advice.

Comment: If you call a web page instead of the API, you will don't get a list of picture but all the HTML of the page :)

Comment: You can send a GET request to the image search url, but like @Slyzz said, you will get the entire HTML of the page, which you will have to scrape through to find your images. Is there any reason why you would not want to use the image search API? Its actually built for scenarios like this.

Comment: Yes, i know that i get HTML with result. Could You please give some example GET URL for IMAGE SEARCH with URL to image what i want to search?

Answer (score 0):

After the one hour of Googling I find the way how to do it:

```
https://www.google.com/searchbyimage?&image_url=YOUR_IMAGE_URL
```

I cannot believe, that this feature is not visible documented in the Official Documentation.